# TypeError: 'CreateEmbeddingResponse' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openaiembeddings

I am trying to run sample code from the openai website for getting embeddings for dataset: [https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/use-cases](https://stackoverflow.com). However, the code returns an error that I can't resolve looking at historical posts

I tried running this code where df is a dataframe I have created with my own data that loaded succesfully.

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

def get_embedding(text, model="text-embedding-ada-002"):
   text = text.replace("\n", " ")
   return client.embeddings.create(input = [text], model=model)['data'][0]['embedding']

df['embedding'] = df.ITEM_DESCRIPTION.apply(lambda x: get_embedding(x, model='text-embedding-ada-002'))
df.to_csv('embedded_output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] to provide a [mre] including the full traceback and whatever input data you used.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 25):

They didn't update their documentation. It is now:

```
def get_embedding(text, model="text-embedding-ada-002"):
    text = text.replace("\n", " ")
    return client.embeddings.create(input = [text], model=model).data[0].embedding
```

Comment: Thank you Florian, your answer works for me. There is a similar case with the ChatCompletion, `TypeError: 'ChatCompletion' object is not subscriptable`

But why this error occurs in the first place, can anyone explain it please?

Comment: It seems `create()` was returning `dict` like object before and returning class instance currently.